# Changing Directories, directly

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, path

I am just starting to familiarise myself on Powershell.

Just a quick question:

If I am in a specific directory, and I wish to go to another directory directly, is this possible?

e.g: current path; test/1/2/3/4/5>, and from this directory I would like to go to

(1)  test/1

(2)  A completely unrelated directory e.g desktop?

Hope this makes sense.

(Windows 10).

Comment: To go from test/1/../5 to test/1 directly, you would have to enter the absolute path. `cd C:\Document\test\1`. Alternatively you can use the `cd ..` command. Each `..` will bring you back up to the parent of the current directory.  `cd ../../..` would bring you up 3 directories. To change to your desktop you would have to do the same thing. cd C:\Desktop. You could also do the smart thing and make an alias to do the major directory switching for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the old times of MS-DOS came CD: Change Directory, now in PowerShell named Set-Location, being CD one of its aliases, this command will help you to change directly to the directory (or folder) that you want.

The help from Set-Location tells us that:

```
NAME
    Set-Location

SYNTAX
    Set-Location [[-Path] <string>] [-PassThru] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Set-Location -LiteralPath <string> [-PassThru] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Set-Location [-PassThru] [-StackName <string>] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    sl
    cd
    chdir


REMARKS
    Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
        -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
        -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help Set-Location -Online" or
           go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113397.
```

So, when using Set-Location you can specify the new path like:

```
Set-Location C:\Windows
```

and the magic happens.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to go from one directory to another, not change the 'home directory's or the path of the command cd~.

Comment: @Gurjinder Change from one directory to another, that's exactly what CD is for, edited and clarified a little. Hope it helps

Comment: The answer is correct. Use `Set-Location` and specify the path of the location you want to change to. If the path contains spaces, you need to quote it.

Comment: Cool, got it . Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `pushd/popd` to temporarily switch to different folders and return to the one previously used.

```
PS> pwd

Path
----
C:\Test\1\2\3\4\5

PS> Push-Location C:\Test\1

PS> pwd

Path
----
C:\Test\1

PS> Pushd ~\Desktop

PS> pwd

Path
----
C:\Users\UserName\Desktop
```